# How to get a sum of child object values in main entity by default

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a PurchaseOrder entity and I have a Payments entity. Inside of the PurchaseOrder entity I'm trying to get the sum of Payments.amountPaid however it doesn't work as expected. Ideally the $allPaid should have a sum of all payments amountPaid for each PurchaseOrder. I was following this tutorial: [enter link description here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/aggregate-fields.html)

Here is my PurchaseOrder entity:

```
class PurchaseOrder
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="RequestForEstimate", fetch="EAGER")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="request_id", referencedColumnName="request_id")
     */
    private $request;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Payment", mappedBy="purchaseOrder", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"persist"}, fetch="EAGER")
     */
    private $payments;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="create_time", type="datetime")
     */
    private $createTime;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="update_time", type="datetime")
     */
    private $updateTime;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="PurchaseOrderStatus", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $status;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="ship_date",type="datetime")
     */
    private $shipDate;

    private $allPaid = 0;


    public function getAllPaid()
    {
        foreach ($this->payments as $payment) {
            $this->allPaid += $payment->amountPaid();
        }
        return $this->allPaid;
    }
    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
    /**
     * Set createTime
     *
     * @param \DateTime $createTime
     *
     * @return PurchaseOrder
     */
    public function setCreateTime($createTime)
    {
        $this->createTime = $createTime;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get createTime
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getCreateTime()
    {
        return $this->createTime;
    }

    /**
     * Set updateTime
     *
     * @param \DateTime $updateTime
     *
     * @return PurchaseOrder
     */
    public function setUpdateTime($updateTime)
    {
        $this->updateTime = $updateTime;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get updateTime
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getUpdateTime()
    {
        return $this->updateTime;
    }

    /**
     * Set status
     *
     * @param integer $status
     *
     * @return PurchaseOrder
     */
    public function setStatus($status)
    {
        $this->status = $status;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get status
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getStatus()
    {
        return $this->status;
    }

    /**
     * Set shipDate
     *
     * @param \DateTime $shipDate
     *
     * @return PurchaseOrder
     */
    public function setShipDate($shipDate)
    {
        $this->shipDate = $shipDate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get shipDate
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getShipDate()
    {
        return $this->shipDate;
    }

    /**
     * Set requestForEstimate
     *
     * @param \InboundBundle\Entity\RequestForEstimate $requestForEstimate
     *
     * @return PurchaseOrder
     */
    public function setRequestForEstimate(\InboundBundle\Entity\RequestForEstimate $requestForEstimate = null)
    {
        $this->requestForEstimate = $requestForEstimate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get requestForEstimate
     *
     * @return \InboundBundle\Entity\RequestForEstimate
     */
    public function getRequestForEstimate()
    {
        return $this->requestForEstimate;
    }

    /**
     * Set requestId
     *
     * @param \InboundBundle\Entity\RequestForEstimate $requestId
     *
     * @return PurchaseOrder
     */
    // public function setRequest(\InboundBundle\Entity\RequestForEstimate $request = null)
    // {
    //     $this->request = $request;
    //     $request->setRequestId($this);
    //     return $this;
    // }
    public function setPayments(Payment $payments = null)
    {
        $this->payments = $payments;

        return $this;
    }


    /**
     * Get requestId
     *
     * @return \InboundBundle\Entity\RequestForEstimate
     */
    public function getRequest()
    {
        return $this->request;
    }

    /**
     * Set request
     *
     * @param \InboundBundle\Entity\RequestForEstimate $request
     *
     * @return PurchaseOrder
     */


    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->payments = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Add payment
     *
     * @param \InboundBundle\Entity\Payment $payment
     *
     * @return PurchaseOrder
     */
    public function addPayment(\InboundBundle\Entity\Payment $payment)
    {
        $this->payments[] = $payment;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove payment
     *
     * @param \InboundBundle\Entity\Payment $payment
     */
    public function removePayment(\InboundBundle\Entity\Payment $payment)
    {
        $this->payments->removeElement($payment);
    }

    /**
     * Get payments
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getPayments()
    {
        return $this->payments;
    }

    /**
     * Set request
     *
     * @param \InboundBundle\Entity\RequestForEstimate $request
     *
     * @return PurchaseOrder
     */
    public function setRequest(\InboundBundle\Entity\RequestForEstimate $request = null)
    {
        $this->request = $request;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Payment entity:

```
class Payment
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="PurchaseOrder", inversedBy="payments", cascade={"persist", "detach"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="purchase_order", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $purchaseOrder;
    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="create_time", type="datetime")
     */
    private $createTime;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="update_time", type="datetime")
     */
    private $updateTime;
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="creator", type="integer")
     */
    private $creator;
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="amount_paid", type="decimal", precision=10, scale=2)
     */
    private $amountPaid;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="PaymentType", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="payment_type", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $paymentType;
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="external_transaction_id", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $externalTransactionId;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="including_fees", type="decimal", precision=10, scale=2)
     */
    private $includingFees;





    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set createTime
     *
     * @param \DateTime $createTime
     *
     * @return Payment
     */
    public function setCreateTime($createTime)
    {
        $this->createTime = $createTime;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get createTime
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getCreateTime()
    {
        return $this->createTime;
    }

    /**
     * Set updateTime
     *
     * @param \DateTime $updateTime
     *
     * @return Payment
     */
    public function setUpdateTime($updateTime)
    {
        $this->updateTime = $updateTime;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get updateTime
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getUpdateTime()
    {
        return $this->updateTime;
    }

    /**
     * Set creator
     *
     * @param integer $creator
     *
     * @return Payment
     */
    public function setCreator($creator)
    {
        $this->creator = $creator;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get creator
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getCreator()
    {
        return $this->creator;
    }

    /**
     * Set amountPaid
     *
     * @param string $amountPaid
     *
     * @return Payment
     */
    public function setAmountPaid($amountPaid)
    {
        $this->amountPaid = $amountPaid;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get amountPaid
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAmountPaid()
    {
        return $this->amountPaid;
    }

    /**
     * Set paymentType
     *
     * @param string $paymentType
     *
     * @return Payment
     */
    public function setPaymentType($paymentType)
    {
        $this->paymentType = $paymentType;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get paymentType
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPaymentType()
    {
        return $this->paymentType;
    }

    /**
     * Set externalTransactionId
     *
     * @param string $externalTransactionId
     *
     * @return Payment
     */
    public function setExternalTransactionId($externalTransactionId)
    {
        $this->externalTransactionId = $externalTransactionId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get externalTransactionId
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getExternalTransactionId()
    {
        return $this->externalTransactionId;
    }

    /**
     * Set includingFees
     *
     * @param string $includingFees
     *
     * @return Payment
     */
    public function setIncludingFees($includingFees)
    {
        $this->includingFees = $includingFees;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get includingFees
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getIncludingFees()
    {
        return $this->includingFees;
    }

    /**
     * Set purchaseOrder
     *
     * @param \InboundBundle\Entity\PurchaseOrder $purchaseOrder
     *
     * @return Payment
     */
    public function setPurchaseOrder(\InboundBundle\Entity\PurchaseOrder $purchaseOrder = null)
    {
        $this->purchaseOrder = $purchaseOrder;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get purchaseOrder
     *
     * @return \InboundBundle\Entity\PurchaseOrder
     */
    public function getPurchaseOrder()
    {
        return $this->purchaseOrder;
    }
}
```

When I dump the object it shows that the allPaid is 0 as set by default:

[image]

Comment: `private $allPaid = 0;` change to `private $allPaid;`

Comment: Well, it is null now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [Doctrine2 postLoad event](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events). The **postLoad** event occurs for an entity after the entity has been loaded into the current EntityManager from the database or after the refresh operation has been applied to it.

```
...
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
...

/**
 * ... 
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 * ...
 */
class PurchaseOrder
{
    ...

    private $allPaid = null;

    /**
     * @ORM\PostLoad
     */
    public function getAllPaid()
    {
        if (null === $this->allPaid) {
            foreach ($this->payments as $payment) {
                $this->allPaid += $payment->amountPaid();
            }
        }

        return $this->allPaid;
    }
}
```

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It looks like when I use both: @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks and @ORM\PostLoad I get the amountPaid doubled. It seems like I only need one of these...

Comment: It is probably because you have called getAllPaid() after the object has fully loaded. 
I updated code example with a check if $this->allPaid is different from null.

Comment: Btw, my answer was some kind of quick fix :)
You should consider timdev's advises, too. Especially situations when you are adding or removing payments.

Answer (score 3):

Matko's answer works, but your question makes implies that you're (or at least you were) missing something fundamental.

In your original code, the internal (private) `allPaid` property is initialized to zero.  Your `getAllPaid()` method computes the actual value and returns it.  As written, `getAllPaid()` will iterate over the payments collection every time it's invoked.

When you dump your entity, the `$allPaid` property is zero because you're dumping **before** `getAllPaid()` was invoked.  If you call `getAllPaid()` and then dump, you'll see it contains the computed value.  That is because `getAllPaid()` sets that value along the way.  Or, instead of dumping (and seeing the uninitialized internal value), test by actually invoking `getAllPaid()` and see that the correct value is returned.

The weakness with Matko's solution is that it eagerly loads the collection every time.  It's likely that there are some scenarios where you need to load a PurchaseOrder without loading all the payments.

Since `$allPaid` is private, you'll always be using `getAllPaid()` to access the value.

To improve your code, I would you **memoize** `$allPaid`

1. Initialize `private $allPaid = null;`.  The semantics of `null` are more appropriate, because upon initialization, the value is not zero.  It's unknown.
2. In getAllPaid(), add a check that `$this->allPaid !== null`, and if so, return early.  That way, repeated calls to `getAllPaid()` don't recompute the value each time.
3. Be sure to clear the memo when the payments collection changes.  `PurchaseOrder::addPayment()` and `PurchaseOrder::removePayment()` should both set `$this->allPaid` to null, forcing the value to be recomputed on the next time `getAllPaid()` is invoked.
4. Finally, remove the eager fetchmode on `PurchaseOrder::payments`.  If you want to eagerly load them in cases where you know you'll need them, you can fetch-join them in your query.